# filtering sequences

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, f#-data

There are three different seq of same size

```
a:int   = {1,  2,  3,  4}
b:string= {"a","b","a","d"}
c:string= {"y","y","t","t"}
```

how can I create a new seq from `seq:a` with condition

```
where b="a" and c="y"
```

Comment: What you should get in the end? {1}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Seq.zip a (Seq.zip b c)
|> Seq.filter (snd >> ((=) ("a", "y")))
|> Seq.map fst
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Seq.zip3 a b c
|> Seq.choose (function (n, "a", "y") -> Some n | _ -> None)
```